# Multiple Inner Join needed to check If rows exist? - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, aql

I've re-submitted this question as it had errors which I believe I have now fixed, apologies.

Ok, the following stored procedure works fine but I need to add another condition in relation to another table called `tblItems`. I require `tblAccounts.accountID` to join with `tblItems.AccountID` so I can check if `tblItems.fileID > 0` and if so, then return results. Here's the tables I have and expected results..

```
TBLACCOUNTS: AccountID, ContactName, SkypeUserName, friendlyOrderID

TBLORDERS: AccountID, ItemsAllowed

TBLITEMS: AccountID, FileID, ImageUrl
```

What I hope to achieve is this..

```
4B900A74-E2D9-4837-B9A4-9E828752716E  PETER     PETE  827365
E82882D9-4837-B9A4-9E82-22228752716E  MATTHEW   MATT  373926
4B900A74-2323-1414-2525235252533333D  JONATHAN  JON   732792...
```

Which is what the first codeblock below does.
But I need only rows where each user has at least 1 fileID in tblItems. The results I'm getting when I try the 2nd code block below are as follows..

```
4B900A74-E2D9-4837-B9A4-9E828752716E  PETER     PETE  827365
4B900A74-E2D9-4837-B9A4-9E828752716E  PETER     PETE  827365
4B900A74-E2D9-4837-B9A4-9E828752716E  PETER     PETE  827365...
```

Codeblock1

```
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE WHEN RowNo < cnt THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS lastbox
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dateAdded DESC) AS [RowNo],
         COUNT(*) OVER () cnt,
         tblAccounts.skypeUserName, tblAccounts.contactName, 
         tblorders.friendlyOrderID
     FROM 
         tblOrders
     INNER JOIN 
         tblAccounts ON tblOrders.accountID = tblAccounts.accountID
     WHERE 
         bootSaleDate = @bootSaleDate AND orderStatus = 'Completed') t
WHERE 
    RowNo BETWEEN (@page * 8) - 7 AND (@page * 8)
```

Here is what I have tried (Codeblock2)..

```
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN RowNo < cnt THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS lastbox
    FROM
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY orderDate desc) as [RowNo],
    COUNT(*) OVER () cnt,
    tblAccounts.skypeUserName, tblAccounts.contactName, tblorders.friendlyOrderID
    FROM tblOrders
    INNER JOIN tblAccounts ON tblOrders.accountID=tblAccounts.accountID
    INNER JOIN tblItems ON tblOrders.accountID=tblItems.accountID
    WHERE EXISTS(select 1 from tblItems WHERE tblItems.fileID > 0 AND tblItems.accountID = 
    tblOrders.accountID AND tblOrders.bootSaleDate = @bootSaleDate)  AND tblOrders.bootSaleDate = 
    @bootSaleDate AND tblOrders.orderStatus='Completed' 
    ) t
WHERE RowNo BETWEEN (@page*8)-7 AND (@page*8)
```

Comment: The exists check seems pointless - an inner join will only find data if a record exists based on the join condition and the joins are cumulative so even if the from and the first inner join find stuff they will be discarded if the last join does not. Maybe you just need the WHERE tblItems.fileID > 0 . Sample data and expected outcome would help.

Comment: @P.Salmon I've updated original question to try and make it a bit clearer as to what i require. Many thanks for helping.

Comment: Not much clearer particularly since what you are trying to achieve doesn't contain the selected items and doesn't have headers. Stepping back a bit is there only 1 row for account in tblaccounts? many for an account in tblorders? and many for an account in tblitems. Also 'has at least 1 fileID in tblItems' is ambiguous it could mean 1 row per account but fileid can have a value 0-n or it could be many rows for an account.

Comment: @P.Salmon Yeah tblItems can have 0,1,2,3,4,5 etc number of rows. I wish to retrieve tblAccounts.skypeUserName, tblAccounts.contactName, tblorders.friendlyOrderID for every user ONLY if a row exists in tblItems for that user and that date. And yes tblorders and tblitems may contain more than one occurance of the same accountID. Does that make sense? Sorry for not fully understanding, i'm still just learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you mean something like this where the sub query s works out how many rows exist for a tblitems with fileid > 0

```
 drop table tblorders
 drop table tblaccounts
 drop table tblitems
 go

 create table tblorders (accountid int,orderdate smalldatetime,friendlyorderid int,
                bootsaledate smalldatetime, orderstatus varchar(10))
 create table tblaccounts(accountid int,skypeusername varchar(3),contactname varchar(3))
 create table tblitems(accountid int,fileid int)
 insert into tblorders values
 (1,'2020-04-29',1,'2020-04-29','completed'),
 (2,'2020-04-29',1,'2020-04-29','completed')

 insert into tblaccounts values
 (1,'aaa','aaa'),
 (2,'bbb','bbb')

 truncate table tblitems
 insert into tblitems values
 (1,0),(2,2),(1,1)
 declare @bootsaledate smalldatetime
 set @bootsaledate = '2020-04-29'
 SELECT tblorders.accountid,tblaccounts.accountid,s.accountid,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY orderDate desc) as [RowNo],
    COUNT(*) OVER () cnt,
    tblAccounts.skypeUserName, tblAccounts.contactName, tblorders.friendlyOrderID
    FROM tblOrders
    INNER JOIN tblAccounts ON tblOrders.accountID=tblAccounts.accountID
    INNER JOIN 
        (select accountid,sum(case when fileid > 0 then 1 else 0 end) fileid 
        from tblitems
        group by accountid) s  ON tblOrders.accountID=s.accountID
    WHERE s.fileID > 0 
    AND tblOrders.bootSaleDate = @bootSaleDate 
    AND tblOrders.orderStatus='Completed' ;

 accountid   accountid   accountid   RowNo                cnt         skypeUserName contactName friendlyOrderID
----------- ----------- ----------- -------------------- ----------- ------------- ----------- ---------------
1           1           1           1                    2           aaa           aaa         1
2           2           2           2                    2           bbb           bbb         1
```

Comment: That's helped loads, thank you. It wasn't quite what I was looking for but I picked some parts of your code solution out which helped me create a solution. I was mainly missing GROUP BY which is why i was getting multiple results. It was a difficult one to explain so thank you for persisting.

Comment: It's not helpful to others on this site if there are questions without answers - you could either publish your own solution or delete the question.